# multiple jquery ui tabs - target one tab from another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs on a long home page (scrolling down).
The page has 3 sections which each use tabs and the viewer scrolls down to each section.

I want to target specific tabs from other pages which works fine if the tabs are at the top of the page. If the tabs are down the page the link opens the correct tab but the page is at the top so until you scroll down you can't see the intended content.

I'm using jQuery tabs in it's most simple form:

```
$('#tabs-mcr > ul').tabs();
$('#tabs-lpool > ul').tabs();
$('#tabs-bham > ul').tabs();
```

Is is possible to find the height from the top of the window or the position of the targeted tabs on the page and jump to that position when the link is clicked...?

P.S.
I'm already using `$(window).scrollTop();` to scoll down to each of the tab sections via the main navigation – if that could be utilised with targeting the tabs that would be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Try the jQuery scrollTo plugin.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/jquery-scrollto-plugin

Comment: How can I link the scrollto function to the tab code?
Sorry, I'm a real newcomer to jQuery

Comment: If memory serves, it will scroll to any selector, such as an ID. But it's been a while--this or similar plugin should do the trick, and also nice and smooth if you want it to. Good luck.

Comment: I'm already using this plugin but it doesn't work with the tabs. For some reason when you link from another page it doesn't scroll to the anchor

Comment: So the link has an hash in it? (i.e. http://blah.com#has) In that case, you might try an onload handler, to detect the hash (window.location.hash) and then call the scrollTo function.